# RewriteMap not working in mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I have been trying to do simple maping with RewriteMap directive in my htaccess, but for some reason i am getting error 500 everytime. my syntax is ..
    Options +FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap name2id txt:nklist.txt
RewriteRule ^/name/(.*) /name_list_view.php?kid=${name2id:$1|NOTFOUND}
```

in nklist.txt :

```
1 David
2 Mark
3 Simon
```

the nklist.txt file is on the root of my website , same place where the htaccess is . As far as my debugging tells me that htaccess is not able to find the nklist.txt file, but any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your description, you're attempting to define a `RewriteMap` in a per-directory context via your `.htaccess` file, but this isn't allowed. The [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) can only be defined in a per-server context, either in the main server configuration or in a virtual server section.

When you make requests to the server and the `.htaccess` file is parsed, it encounters the `RewriteMap` directive and issues an alert, which results in an 500 error being thrown. You'll likely see an entry in your `error_log` that states "RewriteMap not allowed here".

Comment: Thanks for the answer,,
so what you mean is i have to move the txt file somewhere in the server folder?
my root path is 
    /home/mobilevi/public_html
Where do you recommend should i put my map file?

Comment: No, it's not an issue with your txt file, it's just that you can't use `RewriteMap` in `.htaccess` because it's not allowed. You have to set it in a server configuration, which you probably cannot do unless you fully control the server. Are you on a shared host, or do you control the server yourself?

Comment: sorry i miss understood you answer, got the point now, i am on share host, but i also have my own server.thanks for the answer though