# Force lowercase .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I tried to do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

But, I receive a 500 internal error. Not sure what's wrong.

Error:

```
/home/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteMap not allowed here
[Mon Jul 18 10:33:06 2011] [alert] [client *.*.*.*] /home/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteMap not allowed here
```

Comment: `/home/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteMap not allowed here
[Mon Jul 18 10:33:06 2011] [alert] [client *.*.*.*] /home/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteMap not allowed here
` <= is the error it throws

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3306070/206403).

Comment: For those coming from google, what you really want is a [canonical meta tag](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization).

Answer (score 3):

`RewriteMap` CANNOT be declared in .htaccess file -- only in server config / virtual hosting context: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

If you cannot edit Apache's config files, then you are out of luck -- you have to implement such redirect using some script -- PHP, for example.

Comment: Do I have to declare RewriteMap in the server config AND in the htaccess, or ONLY in the server config?

Comment: Only in the vhost config or server config as you say.

Answer (score 3):

If your using PHP you could put this in the beginning of your index.php

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pattern = '/([A-Z]+)/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $url)) {
    $new_url = strtolower($url);

    Header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
    Header( 'Location: ' . $new_url );
    exit;
}

// your code here
```

Comment: This will lowercase also the querystring, which can lead to problems.
If for some reason you really have to do this, split the path and the querystring with the parse_url function and lowercase only the path.